# Calculating the percent change between two values in R and off by one issue

Tags: r, function

I am trying to calculate the percent change between two points in R in the form of:

```
(X_(i+1) - X_(i))/(X_(i))
```

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
#x is a vector from the dataframe
#lag is distance between two points being compared
percent_change = function(x,lag = 1)
{
    n = length(x)
    pchange = c((x[(1+lag):n] - x[1:(n-lag)])/x[1:(n-lag)],NA)
    return(pchange)
}
```

However, in order to accomplish this task in R I had to bind an NA to avoid:

```
Error in \`$<-.data.frame\`(\`*tmp*\`, "Change", value = c(0.00248221082243916,  : 
  replacement has 4616 rows, data has 4617
```

With this addition, the operation occurs and aligns to what I've calculate it should be on paper.

Is there a way where I do not have to append an NA?

Comment: you don't appear to be using a data frame at all - is that in the code that calls this function?

Comment: If you don't store it back to the data frame then you don't need the NA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do need the `NA` if you want to store the `pc_change` result back in the original data frame:

Since the last element of your array does not have an `x+1` to compare to it will produce a vector 1 (or lag) shorter than the original.

---

**Warning:** Note that you have one `NA` added - this is correct for the case `lag=1` but more generally you need need `lag` × `NA` elements.

Try replacing `NA` with `rep(NA,lag)`.

---

Here's a more compact version of your function using the built-in `diff` function:

```
pcchange=function(x,lag=1) c(diff(x,lag),rep(NA,lag))/x
```

Comment: Ahh! That is far more compact than what I came up with.
One question:
Syntax wise can any operation (+,-,*,%, ..) be performed on c(diff(x,lag),rep(NA,lag), ..)?

Comment: Diff is obviously the subtract operation.  Apart from that, no you should synthesize your own as above.  You could always look at the source to diff: type `diff.default` at your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To me, adding the NA seems like a valid solution. However, there are functions to perform this kind of operations. Take a look at `lag` function to get lagged timeseries. In general for timeseries analysis, look at the the `xts` and `zoo` packages for handeling of timeseries. The [CRAN TaskView dedicated to timeseries](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) is also a valueable source of information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely it out. I didn't realize there was such a centralized location for this information.